# Reference to vector as class member

Tags: c++, class, vector, reference

I tried to pass a vector as a class member by reference but I seem to have passed it by value.

So I am making a class that has a function that can change the position of an element in a vector. The code looks like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Example {
    int x, y;
    vector<vector<string>> chart;
public:

    Example(int i, int j, vector<vector<string>>& arr);
    void Swap_up();
};

Example::Example(int i, int j, vector<vector<string>>& arr) :x(i), y(j), chart(arr) {
}

void Example::Swap_up() {
    if (x - 1 >= 0 && chart[x - 1][y].at(0) == ' ') {
        string temp = chart[x-1][y];
        chart[x - 1][y] = chart[x][y];
        chart[x][y] = temp;
        x = y - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < chart.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chart[0].size(); j++) {
                cout << '[' << chart[i][j] << ']';
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Invalid move" << endl;

}




int main() {

    int chart_height;
    int chart_width;
    cout << "Enter height of the chart in number of spaces (Minimum number of spaces is 7)" << endl;
    cin >> chart_height;
    cout << "Enter width of the chart in number of spaces (Minimum number of spaces is 7)" << endl;
    cin >> chart_width;


    vector<vector<string>> chart; 
        chart.resize(chart_height);
    for (int i = 0; i < chart_height; i++)
        chart[i].resize(chart_width);

    for (int i = 0; i < chart_height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < chart_width; j++) {
            if (chart[i][j] == "")
                chart[i][j].insert(0, 3, '  ');
        }
    }



    chart[6][5] = "EXA"; 
    for (int i = 0; i < chart_height; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < chart_width; j++) {
            cout << '[' << chart[i][j] << ']';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;


    Example Exa1(6, 5, chart); 
    Exa1.Swap_up();


    for (int i = 0; i < chart_height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < chart_width; j++) {
            cout << '[' << chart[i][j] << ']';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    chart.clear();
    chart.resize(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I thought I had used a reference to the vector as a member of my class. So I had the program print the chart with the element in its original position and then execute swap_up, so the class method moves the element up a space and prints the chart again. This worked.

The problem is that then I had the program print the chart a third time and the element was back in its original position. So I obviously passed the vector as a class member by value and not by reference, so the class method didn't actually change the chart but a copy of it. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The chart data member of your example class is not a reference. In the constructor you pass a reference of an object, but use that object to create a copy. I believe your constructor will actually invoke the copy constructor of the vector class.

Comment: "*class attribute*" The word you're looking for is member, not attribute. ["Attribute" in C++ means something very different](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought I had used a reference to the vector as an attribute of my class.

No. You passed a reference to a vector as a parameter to your class's constructor. That's all you did.

Your constructor assigned it to its class member. It is very important to use correct terminology when discussing C++. C++ is complicated enough so that inconsistent terminology often leads to confusion.

```
vector<vector<string>> chart;
```

This is a commonly described as a class member, not an "attribute".

As you can see, it is not a reference. It is a discrete object. This means that when the constructor initializes the class member

```
... chart(arr)
```

the referenced vector gets copied into `chart`, a discrete object.

Subsequent changes to `chart` have no effect on the vector that was passed, by reference, to the constructor. After all, why should it? It's a vector, on its own merits.

If your expectations were that the original vector should be affected then the class member, itself, should be a reference:

```
class Example {
    int x, y;
    vector<vector<string>> &chart;
```

Then, the `chart` reference gets initialized from the reference to the parameter that gets passed to the constructor, and subsequent changes to `chart` reference that vector.

This kind of design is problematic for other reasons, generally, but they are immaterial to the question.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry about the terminology, I am obviously very very new at this. If I may ask, what are the reasons for the design being problematic?

Comment: You now have a class that carries a reference to some other object that exists somewhere else. The class has no control over the referenced object's lifetime. If before calling `Swap_up` the referenced vector gets destroyed, as a result of any other things that might happen, undefined behavior results, and almost a guaranteed crash, or, worse yet: some random behavior and memory corruption that results in a crash somewhere else, for no apparent reason whatsoever.

Comment: @sam_varshavchik Would the same issue exist if I used a pointer to that vector as a class member?

Comment: Yes it would. There's a dark, deeply held secret that's only known to select few C++ gurus: a pointer and a reference is the exact, same thing, differing only in semantics, syntax, and different compiler optimizations. Now you know the secret.